# How to pass data From VC to Cell?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, cell

i am wondering how I can pass data from a ViewController to a cell?

I am a beginner so I may oversee the obvious :P

I have a home VC and when you press on a commentButton you get to the CommentVC which holds the postId of the post.
As I want to be able to like a comment( which works perfectly) and to notice the user about his comment being liked(which does not work for now) I need to have the postId not only in the commentVC ( which holds the correct one) but also in the cell.

this is the code where I pass data from the HomeVc to the CommentVC

```
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "CommentSegue" {
        let commentVC = segue.destination as! CommentViewController
        let commentCell = CommentTableViewCell()
        let postId = sender as! String
        commentCell.postId = postId
        commentVC.postId = postId
    }
}
```

When I print out both variables in CommentVc and CommentCell, only the CommentVc shows the correct one whereas the Cell has "nil" as the print out statement.

Any Idea how I can pass it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not pass a table cell. Since you already passed the postId to your comment view controller, you can access to this id from a table view cell in your comment view controller in this way

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "EditorFontCell") as! EditorFontCell

    print(self.postId)
    //do what you want with postId with the current cell object here

    return cell
}
```

Now remove the cell in segue

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "CommentSegue" {
        let commentVC = segue.destination as! CommentViewController
        let postId = sender as! String
        commentVC.postId = postId
    }
}
```

Comment: @Zash__ np dont forget to mark as correct answer. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't instantiate `UITableViewCell`s yourself by calling your custom classes initialiser, but you should do it in your `UITableViewController` class (or a class that conforms to `UITableViewContollerDataSource` protocol).

Pass the data you want to show in your cells to your table view controller and in your data source methods (for example `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)`) when creating your cell using `dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:)` assign the data to the specific cell.

Answer (score 1):

Where did you perform the print out statement? Typically, it is recommended to pass any data to the cell view in `cellForRow` of `TableView` delegate method. Inside the cell class, you can have a `configure(_ myId: String)` method with the id as one of the parm to be passed in. Then print it inside that method.

Answer (score 0):

```
//In cell table cell class create a variable to hold the data. Here I made postId as String variable.

 class EditorFontCell: UITableViewCell{
     var postId: String!   // postId may be other type

     override func awakeFromNib() {
            super.awakeFromNib()
            // Initialization code
        }

    }


// in this method you create an object i.e. cell,  of type EditorFontCell
// and you can access that postId by this tableCell object. You can simple assign a value to as shown below.

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "EditorFontCell") as! EditorFontCell

       cell.postId = "String data"
        return cell
    }
```

Comment: put some text and explanation for it. Throwing a code without explanation won't be much help to the OP